# Creating a Spring Cloud microservice

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I am trying to learn and create a microservice using Spring Cloud. I am using Spring mvc and Spring Boot for development. I added separate Spring Boot application for both Eureka server and Zuul client. I have three Spring Boot application now. One Sureka server, one for Zuul routing and third one is for my microservice application. I run the Eureka server and the microservice and Zuul found to be running properly in Eureka server UI.

- My doubt is that, I am planned to use routing and service discovery in my microservice. So I have a total of three Spring Boot applications. Can I deploy these three applications into AWS Elastic Beanstalk?
- When I exploring I found that Pivotal Cloud Foundry topic. Since I am planing to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk. So what is the role of Pivotal Cloud Foundry in my application?

I am still confused about microservice development using Spring Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So  there are two elements in your confusion. Is Amazon Beanstalk suitable?
So answer is yes. but you have overhead of orchestrating various services of amazon over then. Basically Amazon Elastic Beanstalk is more form based which means you need to tell what exactly you want to do with application for example route setup , scaling mechanism , application portability, application health management , Integration with external log aggregators etc.  This is big learning curve to many people (including me :) ). Where as these with **PCF** these things are easy and straightforward and sometimes implicitly done.
Now Can I use pivotal cloud foundry with amazon? answer will be absolutely yes.

Pivotal cloud foundry is Wrapper written over open source Cloud Foundry project.
It is more succinct  PaaS option than Amazon Beanstalk. You can host PCF on amazon ec2 ( IaaS )boxes using BOSH software. To answer you PCF is a alternative to Amazon Beanstalk. **You don't need PCF is you want to use Amazon Beanstalk and vice versa.**

Comment: I am using spring boot with spring cloud tools like Zuul routing and Eureka for service discovery. Can i deploy my microservice in AWS beanstalk? My confusion is whether the spring cloud tools is tightly coupled on PCF? Can i use spring cloud tools for creating services and deploy in beanstalk instead of PCF? I have confusion that spring cloud tools only support with PCF? Since I am new to this service platform. Can you help to clarify this ?

Comment: Zuul , Eureka and all are part of Spring cloud project. Spring Cloud and Spring Boot procidings are cloud provider agnostics. They can run on any cloud provider which can execute java. Namely say Heroku, AWS , PCF , Google Cloud. I think that beanstalk have coverage for service discovery, and zuul  because these technologies are widely adopted. But I need to more research for it.

Comment: Ok..thank you for your response Mr. Pra Jazz. Your response is making me more closer to cloud structure.I also felt confusion in your comment. That statement is - "but you have overhead of orchestrating various services of amazon over then". Actually i did not got the core concern that you mentioned here. May I know more about this statement??

Comment: Yes I can Elaborate more on that. I am including related content in my answer.

Comment: Also keep in 1 thing in mind. Design your app in such a way that you can be easily host your application to any given cloud without or very little modification in application. this art is called as Cloud Native application. 12 cloud native factors can certainly help you in that.